# C++ IDE for Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, git, gcc, sublimetext2

I usually use Xcode to develop C++ applications on my mac; however, I want to move to GCC 4.7.2. The latest version that Xcode supports is 4.2. Does anybody know how I can change the compiler in Xcode so that I can use gcc 4.7.2? If this is not possible, do any of you recommend another IDE? I am currently looking into eclipse, as I use it for Java development.

I can also use Makefiles and compile from the terminal, so would there be a better way solution than using an IDE? I have read about sublime text 2 which is a powerful text editor. I could use that for my C++ projects and and just compile from the terminal. Would that be the best option? Also, is there a way to integrate sublime text 2 with git as I use git extensively. If you do recommend Sublime Text 2, could you also give me some plugins that would be useful to use for C++ development?

Comment: Try eclipse CDT for a full feature IDE. If you like plain Notepad++ like editor, TextWrangler is also a popular option

Comment: If you are used to Eclipse, then try Eclipse CDT for C++. Concerning the toolchain, in the old days it used to be easy to install recent versions of GCC from macports.org. I am not sure if that has changed, you may have to install ``make`` and other build tools too. I just tend to use Makefiles plus emacs of vim.

Comment: Sublime Text can start builds and help to debug them.  No need for terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the compiler in the project build settings. Click on the project file in the listing on the left, choose "Build Settings", find "Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C" and choose other. You probably have to specify the full path.

It should be noted that gcc 4.7 is not able to compile Objective-C on OS X 10.8 and probably 10.7, it can't parse Apple's latest syntax additions. But if you stick to pure C++ you should be ok.

Whether to use and IDE or not is largely subjective. Personally I only use XCode for Obj-C projects, but that's up to you.

Comment: If I go into the build settings, I only see 4 options. One of them is other, how do I specify gcc 4.7 in here?

Comment: You type the path to the compiler. If installed by macports it'd be /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7

Comment: I tried that but that did not work. I even tried other compiler options in that folder. It doesn't matter though, I think I am going to use sublime text and build from there. Then I can compile with the terminal when I need to.